# My Form won't load

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

This is the code for my LoginForm for my program. When I enter my details and click ok; it just freezes and no error comes up, what do I do?

I don't have any idea what to do. I checked was the problem in the form that loads after you click ok and it wasn't the problem. I deleted the code to check and it still froze.

```
           Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
    Dim Servtxt As String
    Dim Usertxt As String
    Dim Passtxt As String
    Dim tbltxt As String
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:/Program Files/Business Elements/Dashboard System Files/LoginServerDAT.txt"
    Try
        Dim lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:/Program Files/Business Elements/Dashboard System Files/LoginServerDAT.txt")
        Servtxt = lines(0)
        Usertxt = lines(1)
        Passtxt = lines(2)
        tbltxt = lines(3)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error! The server configuration file does not exist. Please setup the server information and save it.", "Woops, something went wrong...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
    'Open Connection
    Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim SQLConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
    Dim ServerString As String = "server=" & Servtxt & ";user id=" & Usertxt & ";password=" & Passtxt & ";database=" & tbltxt
    SQLConnection.ConnectionString = ServerString
    Dim MsgResponse As MsgBoxResult
    Try
        SQLConnection.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgResponse = MessageBox.Show("Connection could not be established to the server, but you can still run in offline mode. If you want to do so then click YES. If otherwise, click NO", "Woops! Something went wrong..", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        If MsgResponse = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            Home.Show()
            Home.ConnectedLabel.Text = "Offline Mode. See website for troubleshooting tips."
            Home.ConnectedLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red
            Home.CurrentUser.Text = ""
            Home.ToolStripStatusLabel1.Visible = False
            Me.Close()
        Else
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Try
    'Sign in..
    If SQLConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open = True Then
        Dim sqlquery = "SELECT * From Users Where Username='" & UsernameTextBox.Text & "' AND Password='" & PasswordTextBox.Text & "'"
        Dim command As New MySqlCommand
        command.Connection = SQLConnection
        command.CommandText = sqlquery
        da.SelectCommand = command
        Dim mydata As MySqlDataReader
        mydata = command.ExecuteReader
        If mydata.HasRows = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Error! Incorrect Login Details. Please contact your Administrator for assistance.")
        Else
            'Check Level..
            CheckAccessLevel()

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code one line at a time using the [debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kya29xtx.aspx)?

Comment: Could you direct me to an article please? I never did that before..

Comment: There is a link embedded in my comment above to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kya29xtx.aspx